# Protégé 5.0: Debug ontologies

Tags: ontology, protege

Why when I want to save the changes I made in an ontology I am working on Protégé 5.0 asks me (and practicaly "makes me") to save also a number of "debug_ontologies"?

The problem is annoying, I do not know why I must store this debug ontologies.

When I open them to see what they contain, there are mostly filled with some contents that I defined in my last change (but not always).

Sometimes I define new entities in my ontology and I can save just fine without the need to save this debug ontologies.

I have searched in the Protégé wiki to get more information about this type of behaviour without success.

I used to work with protégé 4.3 before and never came accross with this kind of situation.

Any help to get more insight about why does this happend would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that is caused by the Ontology Debugger Plugin v.0.1.0_BETA. This plugin has been released on August 2nd 2016 for Protégé 5.0.

The Ontology Debugger is creating and using anonymous ontologies as a working copy of the currently loaded ontology to find inconsistencies/incoherencies in the ontology.
Unfortunately, the version v.0.1.0_BETA does not properly clean them up when they are not used anymore by the debugger.
Therefore you are asked to save them too.

The next release 0.1.1_BETA should fix this bug and will be released soon.

If you do not need to debug your ontologies you can alternatively uninstall the plugin by removing the jar file "*org.exquisite.protege-0.1.0.BETA.jar*" from your Protégé's plugins sub-directory and re-start Protégé.

Comment: As promised, a new version of the Ontology Debugger Plugin (v0.1.1.BETA) has been release on September 14th 2016 that hopefully fixes the issue.